# ASP.Net e C# - Reduzindo opções de DropDownList de acordo com data atual

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data, dropdown

No site do meu cliente, eu possuo em uma página um DropDownList com os meses do ano. Infelizmente, a propriedade value está com os meses escritos ao invés dos números.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMesReajuste" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
    <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="Selecione o mês de reajuste" Selected></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Janeiro" Text="Janeiro"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Fevereiro" Text="Fevereiro"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Março" Text="Março"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Abril" Text="Abril"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Maio" Text="Maio"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Junho" Text="Junho"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Julho" Text="Julho"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Agosto" Text="Agosto"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Setembro" Text="Setembro"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Outubro" Text="Outubro"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Novembro" Text="Novembro"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Dezembro" Text="Dezembro"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Eu precisava que esse Dropdown "sumisse" com algumas opções de meses. Por exemplo, hoje é dia 21/6. Então eu só deveria ter acesso às opções de Agosto em diante. Mas quando passar de 10/7, aí eu teria acesso às opções de Setembro em diante.

Ou seja, as opções são sempre do mês seguinte em diante (se estivermos antes do dia 11 do mês atual) e dois meses depois do atual pra se estivermos a partir do 11 até o último dia do mês atual.

Claro que pro mês de novembro, teria só Dezembro se estivermos antes de 11/11. E pra dezembro, todos os meses ficariam disponíveis, menos o de Janeiro se estivessemos em 11/1.

Sei que parece meio complicado, mas eu fiquei na dúvida como fazer alguma coisa em cima disso porque não é possível colocar ID nos ListItems e também porque os Values dos items estão os meses escritos.

O que eu poderia fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo o que eu entendi do seu problema, você quer que adicione 1 mês após o atual quando o dia for menor que 11 e que adicione 2 meses quando o dia for maior do que 11. Fiz um trecho de código para esta situação.

Altere seu dropdown dessa forma.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMesReajuste" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Adicione

```
public void PopularDropDown()
{
        int quantidadeMesesAdicional = 1;

        if (DateTime.Today.Day > 11)
            quantidadeMesesAdicional = 2;

        int indiceMes = DateTime.Today.Month + quantidadeMesesAdicional;

        //Se o indice for 13 irá voltar para 1 que é Janeiro. 
        //Se o indice for 14 irá voltar para 2 que é Fevereiro.
        if (indiceMes == 13)
            indiceMes = 1;
        else if (indiceMes == 14)
            indiceMes = 2;

        Dictionary<byte, string> dictionaryDatas = new Dictionary<byte, string>();

        dictionaryDatas.Add(1, "Janeiro");
        dictionaryDatas.Add(2, "Fevereiro");
        dictionaryDatas.Add(3, "Março");
        dictionaryDatas.Add(4, "Abril");
        dictionaryDatas.Add(5, "Maio");
        dictionaryDatas.Add(6, "Junho");
        dictionaryDatas.Add(7, "Julho");
        dictionaryDatas.Add(8, "Agosto");
        dictionaryDatas.Add(9, "Setembro");
        dictionaryDatas.Add(10, "Outubro");
        dictionaryDatas.Add(11, "Novembro");
        dictionaryDatas.Add(12, "Dezembro");

        ListItemCollection lista = new ListItemCollection();

        foreach (var data in dictionaryDatas.Where(w => w.Key >= indiceMes))
        {
            lista.Add(new ListItem(data.Value, data.Value));
        }

        ddlMesReajuste.DataSource = lista;
        ddlMesReajuste.DataBind();
}
```

Por fim faça a chamada desse método no seu Page_Load dentro de um bloco if (!IsPostBack)

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            PopularDropDown();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Perfeito, funcionou muito bem aqui. Obrigado!!!